# When is the restriction of a fibration to a subspace a fibration?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fibration

Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ be a fibration and $E_0\subset E$ a subset.

When is the restriction $p_0=p|:E_0\rightarrow B$ also a fibration?

It seems like there should be some simple conditions which guarantee this, but I couldn't find any. For concreteness we may assume that $p$ is a surjective Hurewicz fibration (i.e. it has the covering homotopy property) over a connected base $B$, and that $p_0$ is also surjective. I'm also willing to assume that all spaces are nice (even CW). I would still be interested in knowing some of the more general results, however.

Comment: If the fiber of $E_0 \to B$ is a deformation retract of the fiber of $E \to B$, then it follows from the five lemma that $E_0$ is a deformation retract of $E$. I guess you're allowing $p_0$ to have a different fiber than $p$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, yes. I care more for the case that the fibres of $p_0$ are not of the same homotopy type the same as those of $p$. In fact this was essentially the motivation for my question.

Comment: I managed to find J. McClendon's paper  *Open Subsets of Fibrations*, Compositio Mathematica, Volume 49 (1983) no. 1, p. 109-119, which gives a partial answer my question and contains many useful references.